# How to make GNU screen return the last return code to the shell when GNU screen ends

Tags: return-value, gnu-screen

I've just noticed GNU screen can run one command at a time, so this statement cannot work :

```bash
$ screen "command1 || command2"
```

but then this does not work either because GNU screen always returns `0` when it ends running `command1` (even if `command1` returns `1`) :

```bash
$ screen command1 || screen command2
```

How to make GNU screen return the last return code to the shell when GNU screen ends ?

Answer (score 0):

```
screen bash -c "command1 || command2"
```

Comment: Code-only answers may work, but adding an explanation helps users understand why.

Comment: @gabor That cannot work, counter-example : `screen bash -c "false || false";echo $?`

Comment: Why don't you run the whole task in screen? Can you please explain what would be your goal?